# validate phone number android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to figure out how this validate phone number to my android works.

I have add the code and whant to validate 46123456789 but the last number (9) doesent add to the phone number.

This i use:

```
/**
     * @param phone
     * @return The number which satisfies the above criteria, is a valid mobile Number.
     * The first digit should contain number between 0 to 9.
     * The rest 9 digit can contain any number between 0 to 9.
     * The mobile number can have 11 digits also by including 0 at the starting.
     * The mobile number can be of 12 digits also by including 46 at the starting
     */
    public static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phone) {
        phone = trimPhoneNumber(phone);
        // The given argument to compile() method
        // is regular expression. With the help of
        // regular expression we can validate mobile
        // number.
        // 1) Begins with 0 or 46
        // 2) Then contains 6 or 7 or 8 or 9.
        // 3) Then contains 9 digits
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0/46)?[0-9][0-10]{9}");

        // Pattern class contains matcher() method
        // to find matching between given number
        // and regular expression
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phone);
        return (m.find() && m.group().equals(phone));
    }

    public static String trimPhoneNumber(String phone) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
            return phone;
        } else {
            try {
                phone = phone.replace("+46", "");
                phone = phone.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");//replace all except 0-9
                return phone;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return phone;
            }
        }
    }
```

Am i missing something

Comment: What do you expect `[0-10]` in your regex to do?

Comment: add 10 numbers.. :)

Comment: First of all, regular expressions don't "add" anything. They are a pattern to check if a string matches or not. Second, `[]` indicates a certain kind of match called a "character class". I suggest you read about these to learn how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```java
^\s*(?:(?:\+?46)|0)(?:\d){9,10}\s*$
```

`^` at start and `$` at end ensure pattern matches the whole input

`\s*` trim any space or tab
`\d` capture any digit

`(?:\d){9,10}` means the pattern `(?:\d)` should be repeated 9 to 10 times.

``
Pattern start with (`+46` or `46`) or `0` follow by 9 or 10 digit.

If it could contain `-` or space between numbers, use this:

```
^\s*(?:(?:\+?46)|0)(?:[- ]*\d){9,10}\s*$
```

You could test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/tZKixU/1)

Comment: it works like a charm, but when i add the number that i have add in the db it says " internet not found " why this happend i dont now.